# Why styles are added to all objects, not to selected ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button that creates block. When i click on the button, pops up a window with the settings of this block. And there i have settings with position of this block. When i create block and give theme position right, all is ok. But when add another block and give position left, left is givven to first and secont block, but not to second. Why?

```js
function showBlockWindow() {
  var modal = $(".modal-block-container");
  if (modal.css('display', "none")) {
    modal.css('display', "grid");
  } else {
    modal.css('display', "none");
  }
}

function addBlock() {
  var widthInp = $("#width").val();
  var heightInp = $("#height").val();
  var align = $(".form-align-block").val();
  var background = "background-color:";
  var backgroundColor = "black";
  var closeTag = ";";
  var width = "width:";
  var percent = "%";
  var px = "px";
  var onclick = 'onclick="editBlock(this)"';
  var margin = "margin:";
  var height = "height:";
  var block = ("<div class='block-" + align + " preview-block' " + onclick + " style=" + background + backgroundColor + closeTag + width +
    widthInp + percent + closeTag + height + heightInp + px + "></div>");

  $(".preview").append(block);

  if (align == "left" || "right") {
    $(".preview .preview-block").css("margin-" + align + "", "auto");
  } else if (align == "center") {
    $(".preview .preview-block").css("margin", "auto");
  }
}

function editBlock(elem) {
  $('.preview-block').removeClass('preview-block');
  $(elem).addClass('preview-block');
  $('.preview-edit-block').show();
}
```

```css
.addBlock {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  list-style: none;
  transition: 0.1s;
  padding: 5px;
}

.modal-block-container {
  justify-content: center;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  display: none;
}

.input-block {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 1%;
}

#width,
#height {
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
}

.edit-block-modal {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.preview-edit-block {
  background: #272822;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="add-block">
  <li class="addBlock" onclick="showBlockWindow()">Пустой блок</li>
</ul>
<div class="modal-block-container">
  <div class="modal-insert-txt">
    <div class="header-modal">
      <h2>Вставить пустой блок</h2>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="edit-block-modal">
      <span>Ширина</span><br>
      <div class="input-block">
        <input type="text" id="width"> %
      </div>

      <span>Длина</span><br>
      <div class="input-block">
        <input type="text" id="height"> px
      </div>
      <span>Выравнивание блока</span>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-align-block">
          <option value="left">Слева</option>
          <option value="center">По центру</option>
          <option value="right">Справа</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt" onclick="addBlock()">Вставить текст</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="preview">


</div>


<div class="preview-edit-block">

</div>
```

Help me please

Comment: `$(".preview .preview-block")` matches all DIVs with that class, not only the one you just appended. You can use `$(".preview .preview-block:last")` to match the last one.

Comment: Have you considered to use CSS only rather than css in javascript?